# Remove the google logo from Google Map search bar

Tags: google-maps

I want to remove the google logo from googlemap search bar and also instead of search button i want to put custom image.Please follow the link

http://googlemapsapi.blogspot.com/2007/11/introducing-googlebar.html

for your reference.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To hide logo  apply css style to ".gels-logo" Css class.

```
.gels-logo{display:none;}
```

if possible use jQuery and remove value of button

```
$(".gels-button").val("")
```

and apply style to gels-button css class too.

But, it is not good ideas to remove Google's logo

Comment: I did the same in the end of page and map generally takes time to load, so my code does not work.To overcome the same i applied delay to the same that deleted the logo but as we are not certain of map load time we can set the exact time to remove the logo.If it takes more time to load than i defined to remove the logo , it does not work.Any other solution you would like to share.

Comment: Check with Google map onload callback methods and put your code in that.